# Correlogram for lagged data

Tags: r, correlation

I want to make a correlogram (line graph) for the correlation between two variables and show how the correlation of the two variables changes with different temporal lags. So I would like to have a graph with the correlation on the y-axis and the lag on the x-axis.

Everything I've seen so far (acf-package etc.) works only with one variable.

Hope anyone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I `ccf` what you need?

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(x)

ccf(x, y)
```

and as line graph:

```
cc <- ccf(x, y)
plot(cc, type="l")
```